# Trigger UI performance check for an application that authenticates with Okta

Tags: python, selenium, okta

I want to simulate a UI performance test using Python, I could use selenium for that, however, my application is tied to Okta and no other way to get to it.

How can I do a UI simulation to test performance or just to see if UI is working and I don't get any error messages or gateway issues.
I dont want to go through the push notification part as this will be a cron job.

Thank you.

I can use selenium as something like this, but how will it work with an application that is Okta integrated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("getting started with python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Do you get push notification in your phone, and wanna simulate the same ?

Comment: I want to avoid that part as this will be a background job. @cruisepandey